# Datastax community edition in windows - Error in creating the test cluster

Tags: opscenter

I recently installed Datastax community edition for windows. As per the installation manual, after successful installation, the Ops Center is supposed to open and show the status of the Test Cluster.

Looks like there was an issue, the Test Cluster did not come up by default. When I tried to create the test cluster there was a failure. Below is the error message in the opscenterd log.

```
INFO: Testing SSH connectivity to blrkec75614l
2014-09-24 20:14:16+0530 [] ERROR: Problem while calling ProvisionClusterController (NameError): global name 'get_output' is not defined
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)

  File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/SecureShell.py", line 206, in get_remote_ssh_key_bulk_by_type
```

Let me know what is the issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of OpsCenter (5.0) does not support provisioning clusters or automatic agent installation if run on a Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks Arre for your reply. Pls. let me know the version that I should use. I am new, will I get to choose the version when using OpsCenter?

Comment: Also, the installation manual suggests that Test Cluster will get created during installation and will show up when the Ops Center is opened after installation. In my case that did not happen. I had to create the 'Test Cluster'. Anything wrong with the installation?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution?